# Planning Cassandra Deployment and configuring storage

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am planning a Cassandra cluster deployment in production.
I will basically be migrating my stuff from mongo to cassandra.

The total data side will be around 5TB(without replication and compression).

- I am in process of deciding the tuning parameters.I am confused in
  setting the directory sizes in yaml.
- How much size should be given to    saved_caches_directory and
  commitlog_directory. I could not found    much info on it.
- How many nodes should I keep considering a combined read write
  request of 10k per second.
- How much disk should be given to data directory. I have read it
  should not be too high ?
- How will commitlog directory be cleaned. Is it auto or manual ?

========================================================================

I am deciding between

- m3.2xlarge(8 core 30Gig ram no ephimeral only SSD EBS) and  i2.2xlarge(8 core 60 Gig with 2
  ephimeral SSD disk 800 G each ) machines

I also have question around how to divide the RAM inside my C* . 8GB is for heap . Where should the rest of RAM go ? All cache settings are part of heap ? Are there any other configs to be used for utilising this memory

Comment: That is 5 questions not one. Arguably,  *none* are programming questions.

Comment: Is there any ops related version of stackoverflow ? @Raedwald

Comment: Yes there is : the Database Administrator forum at Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a lot of questions, but here's my take on it.

I'd suggest using the default values for sizes to start, and only look at modifying the parameters if you encounter a problem. The defaults will generally do what you need.

The commit log files get re-used, so the storage space is usually not a concern. Looking at one of my nodes, it is only using 200 MB for commitlogs. You do not need to manually clean them or worry about it since it is maintained automatically.

The size of the saved caches might be somewhat application dependent, but I think the size would usually be small on disk since the files are intended to be loaded into memory for a restart.

For sizing the number of nodes, I would suggest prototyping your application by simulating the read and write pattern you expect, and use realistic sizes for what you insert and read. The performance will be greatly influenced by how you write your client application, based on things like your schema, the replication factor, how well the data compresses, etc.

So you would benchmark your prototype application on a small number of test nodes and figure out the peak *sustained* transaction rate that it can handle. Then figure that you'll get a fairly linear increase in transaction rate when adding more nodes, and you can project how big your production cluster would need to be. I'd suggest having enough nodes to handle at least double your expected transaction rate so that you have the capacity to handle things like repairs, boostrapping new nodes, compaction, etc.

When benchmarking, be sure to run the test for as long as possible (several days if possible), and have the full amount of data you expect to store on the cluster since only then will you get the true picture of how it is handling compaction and repair of that much data. An improper way to benchmark would be to run the test for 10 minutes, observe an awesome transaction rate since everything is writing to RAM, and then wrongly conclude that the system could sustain that awesome rate.

Having lots of memory is good up to a point. Cassandra will allocate one quarter of the RAM for the heap by default, with a maximum of 8 GB. So beyond 32 GB of RAM you're probably not getting much bang for the buck. SSD's are a good idea, but I often find the CPU power can be more of a limiting factor. At high transaction rates you will see all the cores working very hard.

The best way to improve performance is to reduce the data load per node. I seen suggestions to stay below 1 TB of data per node, but the smaller the better. You also have to allow for a lot of extra space since things like compaction and repair will generate big temporary files. Also if you use TTL to delete old data, it's important to know that expired data will not be immediately freed on disk, but only during compactions. And compactions may be triggered very infrequently unless you are constantly inserting new data. For some compaction strategies the biggest SSTables are compacted the least often, so may contain a lot of expired data that uses up a lot of disk space.